# on mouse or pointer down not working in chrome

Tags: javascript

Why is this javascript working in ie but not chrome. When I click the span in ie the mouse down works. However i have to double click it in chrome for it to work. What am I doing wrong?

The span is the arrow on the side of this combo box:

```
        <div class="searchcombobox" runat="server" style="z-index:1">
                <asp:TextBox id="searchDepotTextBox" runat="server" style="height: 20px" maxlength="41"/>
                <asp:TextBox id="hdnDepotKey" runat="server" Text="-1" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="DepotSelect" style="display:none" />
                <span style="height: 22px">▼</span>
                <div class="dropdownlist" id="divDepotDropDown" runat="server" style="width: 323px">
                </div>
```

[image: Picture of combo box]

```
var pick = document.getElementById(object_name).parentNode.getElementsByTagName('SPAN');
pick[0].onmousedown = function () {
    spanFocused = true;
    skipBlur = true;
    if (parobject.dropdownlist.style.display != 'block') {
        parobject.dropdownlist.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        parobject.dropdownlist.style.display = 'none';
    }
    parobject.search.focus();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `onclick` instead of `onmousedown`? They are basically the same in most cases. Also, prefer `addEventListened('<event-name>')` to `.on<event-name>` as it allows to attach several events instead of only one

Comment: Oh. That worked. I will just have to code a work around for if they click a second time it closes the list. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'pointerdown' event instead of 'mousedown'. To ensure it works cross browser (Which i think it does anyway) you could wrap the function conditionally:

```
if (isEventSupported("onpointerdown")) {
    var pick = document.getElementById(object_name).parentNode.getElementsByTagName('SPAN');
pick[0].onpointerdown = function () {
        spanFocused = true;
        skipBlur = true;
        if (parobject.dropdownlist.style.display != 'block') {
            parobject.dropdownlist.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
        parobject.dropdownlist.style.display = 'none';
        }
        parobject.search.focus();
    }
} else if (isEventSupported("ontouchstart")) {
    var pick = document.getElementById(object_name).parentNode.getElementsByTagName('SPAN');
pick[0].ontouchstart = function () {
        spanFocused = true;
        skipBlur = true;
        if (parobject.dropdownlist.style.display != 'block') {
            parobject.dropdownlist.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
        parobject.dropdownlist.style.display = 'none';
        }
        parobject.search.focus();
    }
} else if (isEventSupported("onmousedown")) {
    var pick = document.getElementById(object_name).parentNode.getElementsByTagName('SPAN');
pick[0].onmousedown = function () {
        spanFocused = true;
        skipBlur = true;
        if (parobject.dropdownlist.style.display != 'block') {
            parobject.dropdownlist.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
        parobject.dropdownlist.style.display = 'none';
        }
        parobject.search.focus();
    }
}
```

Obviously it could be far more DRY than the example though

Comment: Sadly I have tried onpointerdown and it does the same as onmousedown for my issue.